# UriMatcher match 'n' path segments

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I have a custom ContentProvider that does background processing for a ShareActionProvider.  The Path of the Uri provided is a full file path (ex: /mnt/sdcard/my.file).  The uri is created as such:

```
content://AUTHORITY/mnt/sdcard/my.file
```

A uri match is described as:

```
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "*", 1);
```

Now this works for:

```
content://AUTHORITY/my.file
```

but it does not work for a full path.  Is there a way to match *any* number of path segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the uri fragment instead:

```
content://AUTHORITY/file.ext#/full/path/to/file.ext
```

You can grab the full path with:

```
uri.getFragment()
```

Answer (score 1):

uriMatcher's wildcard * matches 1 segment at a time, so if you want to match

```
content://AUTHORITY/mnt/sdcard/my.file
```

You should use

```
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "*/*/*", 1);
```

Which probably is not what you would like, as you must know how many segments you are receiving. So probably you should implement your own way to match the uris and extract the segments you need (something like uri.getPathSegments(), and iterate through the segments to get each part of the path).

Bests.